# prolog IDE in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ide, prolog

I am starting off learning Prolog. I am on Ubuntu 9.10, can someone suggest an IDE to me ? Unfortunately SCITE doesn't support Prolog and I am trying to avoid Eclipse and NetBean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an IDE user myself, but SWI-Prolog features one called XPCE and PCE Emacs. Install with `sudo apt-get install swi-prolog-xpce`, start by issuing `xpce` in a terminal window, then `emacs.` (with period) to get into the editor. Documentation at [the SWI-Prolog website](http://www.swi-prolog.org/PceEmacs.html).

Prolog support for GNU Emacs is in the `prolog-el` package (no experience with that).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at these Emacs modes:

- [Prolog Mode for Emacs](http://bruda.ca/emacs/prolog_mode_for_emacs) Works well in Emacs24 (haven't tested with earlier versions)
- [The Ciao System](http://ciaohome.org/screenshots.html) Ciao offers a complete Prolog system, supporting ISO-Prolog, but its novel modular design allows both restricting and extending the language. Supports an Emacs mode as well.

And just for the records, if people looking for a Prolog editor or IDE running in Linux end up here: Three Eclipse Prolog plugins.

- [Prolog Development Tool (PDT)](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start)
- [Prolog Development Tools (ProDT)](http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/project-info.html)
- [SICStus Prolog IDE (SPIDER)](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/spider/site/index.html)

I've used PDT on Linux, but only for learning the basics of Prolog, and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I was a happy user of SWI Prolog (`sudo apt-get install swi-prolog`).

Comment: Sorry, it appears IDE is included in an another package  (I used SWI Prolog some 7 years ago).